# MSBuild SvnInfo - which Target Inputs are correct?

Tags: svn, msbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks, msbuild-target

I use [SvnInfo task](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) in MSBuild script:

```
<SvnInfo LocalPath="$(Sources)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
</SvnInfo>
```

`$(Sources)` contains source files only.

Obviously `SvnInfo` depends on files in `$(Sources)`. 
Target then uses info to generate output file with revision number.

In fact I want to run SvnInfo when revision number is changed, but not to run Target (use incremental build) when Revision number is the same as previous run.

How to specify correctly input in target (attribute `Inputs` in `Target` tag, which contains call of `SvnInfo` task)?

I made it in the following way:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Target1Inputs Include="$(Sources)\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="Target1" Inputs="@(Target1Inputs)" Outputs="...">
  ...
  <!-- SvnInfo call here -->
  <!-- File with revision number is created here -->

</Target>
```

It seems to me its workaround, because ideally I should know which files `SvnInfo` depends on without guessing. Is it possible to obtain such info?

I am also not aware whether `.svn` folders are modified or not.

Comment: So you asking how-to fill in "@(Target1Inputs)"  by files or which input you mean?

Comment: @sllev I am asking what to specify in Input attribute of Target tag. I proposed my variant, but I am not sure. (Updated question)

Comment: See my answer, if you mean something else please let me know as well

Answer (score 0):

Basically in this way:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExcludePdbs>$(YourOutputPath)\**\*.pdb</ExcludePdbs>
  <ExcludeTmp>$(YourOutputPath)\**\*tmp*</ExcludeTmp>
</PropertyGroup>

<!-- Prepare set of files -->
<ItemGroup>
   <Files Include="$(FilesToIncludeFolder)\**\*.*"
          Exclude="$(ExcludePdbs);$(ExcludeTmp);$(ExcludeOtherFiles);"/>
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Pass into the target -->
<Target Name="Target1" Inputs="@(Files)" Outputs="..." />
```

**EDIT: The question was updated so here is my update as well**

Supposing you can handle revision changed state, you can add `Condition` to a `Target` and run it depends on property `$(RevisionWasChanged)`.

```
<Target Condition="$(RevisionWasChanged)=='True'"` />
```

Also to control build script execution flow you can use `<Choose>` feature:

```
<Choose>
    <When Condition="$(RevisionWasChanged)=='True'">
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
    </Otherwise>
</Choose>
```

Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: When running my task with incorrect Inputs, sources could be updated, but due to the incremental build Target is not executed. In fact I want to run SvnInfo when revision number is changed, but not to run Target (use incremental build) when Revision number is the same. In Include attribute I specified folder with sources only.

Comment: @sergdev : you've to add this details to the answer because they are matter

Comment: In fact simple way to calculate `$(RevisionWasChanged)` is one of the possible answers to my question.